# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];   
    $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
    $cargo=$_POST['cargo'];
    $division=$_POST['division'];
    $departamento=$_POST['departamento'];

    include "conexion.php"

     if (! [isset ($_POST['BtnEnviar'] ] ); {

        $queryInsertar=$mysqli->query ( "INSERT INTO datos_generales (nombre,apellido,cedula,cargo,division,departamento) values ('$nombre','$apellido','$cedula','$cargo','$division','$departamento')");

         echo "<span><br><br>Datos enviados exitosamente</span><br><br>";
         } elseif ($_POST) 

           {
          echo "<span><br><br>Datos NO ENVIADOS<br><br></span>";
           }

?>
```

Comment: te falta un ; al final del include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar el problema está en los paréntesis que están de forma errónea anidado.

Tienes 2 paréntesis de apertura y uno de cierre. Además el punto y coma te cierra el bloque `if` por lo que el php no tiene sentido las sentencias `else` porque has hecho un `if` sin instrucciones.

Prueba a reemplazar la sentencia del if por esta otra

```
if (! (isset ($_POST['BtnEnviar'] ))) {
```

Comment: gracias fuiste de mucha ayuda...